# Missing Nautilus integration following Ubuntu-One reinstall

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one, nautilus, re-installation

I had problems syncing! Ubuntu One would kick out error messages about being unable to connect but `syncdaemon` would continue chewing through resources until Ubuntu itself crashed. I tried everything to stop the `syncdaemon` but to no avail even after reboot and eventually removed Ubuntu One.

I've now successfully added back Ubuntu One and my "Ubuntu One" folder is syncing fine and `syncdaemon` appears to now be behaving correctly. However I seem to have completely lost Nautilus integration. I have no option to sync any folder other than the "Ubuntu One" folder. I have no Ubuntu One options when I right click folders.

I read about `u1sdtools` and I understand how to unsubscribe from folders using this tool but not how to add them.

When I type `u1sdtool --list-folders` in terminal it replies `No Folders`, I assume I need to use `u1sdtool --subscribe-folder=FOLDER_ID` however everything I could find suggests I find the folder ID by using `--list-folders` and of course there aren't any.

Bring back that Ubuntu One Folder ribbon and all is forgiven!

Anyone any ideas? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nautilus integration is provided by `ubuntuone-client-gnome`. You probably are also missing the control panel, from `ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk`.

For `u1sdtool`, you need to know that you can create a folder (using `u1sdtool --create-folder`), let it sync as much or as little as you want, and then unsubscribe from it (using `u1sdtool --unsubscribe-folder`). From that point onwards no changes to the folder will be synced to nor from the cloud. You can then resubscribe to it (using `u1sdtool --subscribe-folder`). You can also delete the folder entirely (using `--delete-folder`).

As of 11.04, folders you created on other computers are not automatically subscribed to. You get a notification, and you can subscribe to them using the control panel.

Comment: perfect! It was ubuntuone-client-gnome that was missing... it didn't show up when I searched Ubuntu Software Centre for "Ubuntu One" I had already got ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk. Many Thanks for the speedy response and resolution. Now to test it and then I'll mark this answered!